# Почему не получается сделать так, чтобы кнопка next page работала в телеботе?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно, чтобы кнопка <kbd>next page</kbd> работала в телеботе.

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

# Обращение к библиотеке. Обращение к классу
bot = telebot.TeleBot('6649259897:AAFTgb8lEaqj4hrH83Mly6ZPjU6Dl2iapG0')

page = 1
count = 10


# Дикоратор для функции через обращение как Боту.
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('текст', callback_data='1'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}!', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_message(call):
    global count
    global page
    if call.data == '1':
        markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Скрыть', callback_data='unseen'))
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{page}/{count}', callback_data=f' '),
               InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Вперёд --->', callback_data=f'next-page'))
        bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Привет!!!", reply_markup=markup)
    # Обработка кнопки - вперед
    if call == 'next-page':
        if page < count:
            page = page + 1
            markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Скрыть', callback_data='unseen'))
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'<--- Назад', callback_data=f'back-page'),
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{page}/{count}', callback_data=f' '),
                        InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Вперёд --->', callback_data=f'next-page'))
            bot.edit_message_text(f'Страница {page} из {count}', reply_markup=markup, chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                                  message_id=call.message.message_id)

    # Обработка кнопки - назад
        elif call == 'back-page':
            if page > 1:
                page = page - 1
                markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Скрыть', callback_data='unseen'))
                markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'<--- Назад', callback_data=f'back-page'),
                       InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{page}/{count}', callback_data=f' '),
                       InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'Вперёд --->', callback_data=f'next-page'))
                bot.edit_message_text(f'Страница {page} из {count}', reply_markup=markup, chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                                  message_id=call.message.message_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот нужная часть кода. *Для кнопки "Назад" можете сами сделать по аналогии, для обучения)*

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    global COUNT
    text = f'{PAGE}/{COUNT}'
    if callback.data == '1':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Скрыть', callback_data='unseen')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=text, callback_data='None')
        btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Вперёд --->', callback_data='next')

        markup.add(btn1)
        markup.add(btn2, btn3)
    
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Привет!!!", reply_markup=markup)
    
    elif callback.data == 'next':
        next_page(callback)

def next_page(callback):
    global PAGE
    PAGE += 1
    if PAGE < COUNT:        
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Скрыть', callback_data='unseen')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='<--- Назад', callback_data='back-page')
        btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{PAGE}/{COUNT}', callback_data='None')
        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Вперёд --->', callback_data='next-page')

        markup.add(btn1)
        markup.add(btn2, btn3, btn4)
        bot.edit_message_text(text=f'Страница {PAGE} из {COUNT}', chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)
```

Если ответ помог, просьба отметить его галочкой слева